# Custom spring boot profiles not getting activated in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to create spring boot profiles for dev, ct, e2e and prod. I am using application-*.yml files to provide the profile specific settings. I am able to activate the ct and prod profile successfully but I cannot activate the dev and e2e profiles.

I have only observed this problem in IntelliJ. Is this a bug in IntelliJ or am I missing something?

I am currently using IntelliJ Community Edition 2020.1 version.
I have tried activating the profile from application.yml, from VM options and from Program Args from within IntelliJ but no luck.
Strangely even the console log gets stuck after printing the spring boot logo. Below is the log snippet:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)
```

After this no log is printed. Again: this only happens for dev, e2e or other profile names, ct and prod work just fine.

Comment: Can you activate those profiles outside of IntelliJ ?

Comment: Can you please confirm whether the app starts? Also share the content of one of those files not working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to incorrect configuration in logback-spring.xml.
There was no appender configured for the custom profile and hence the logs were not being written to console. The app was correctly getting activated, only the logs were not being printed.